# What is the word for a woman who is interested in prostitution?

Tags: single-word-requests

I would like to know what is the term for a woman who is interested in prostitution, since I remember coming across a word at one point in a text, upon which when I looked it up in the OED, it told me that it meant a woman who is interested in prostitution or being a prostitute. The woman I am describing would be similar to the woman Catherine Deneuve plays in Luis Bunuel's "Belle Du Jour". Anyone not familiar with the movie it is about a woman who becomes interested in prostitution, not for the sake of making money, but because it sexually intrigues her.

I hope that someone may be able to help me with finding this word and that I am not mistaken in believing so.

Thank you.

Comment: Not everything has a word.

Comment: A female George Plimpton?  He is famous for becoming something he wasn't, such as a football player, a golf pro, a "professional" boxer, or a musician in a symphony orchestra, as a kind of immersion journalist. He didn't just interview football players, boxers, etc., but he became them for a short time.  In other words, he walked a mile in their moccasins!

Answer (score 1):

It seems unlikely there is a specific word for someone interested in prostitution. There are a few words used to describe people interested in *generic* occupations:

- student
- apprentice
- padawan

And this would be combined with the specific occupation:

> She is apprenticing to become a prostitute.
>
> He is studying prostitution as a potential career.

But, honestly, these are a little ridiculous when applied to prostitution. You are either a prostitute or not a prostitute; is hard to define what a "not quite a prostitute but could be one day" is without devolving into slanderous terms such as "slut" or "promiscuous."

In the end, I feel comfortable claiming that no such word exists.

Comment: Or perhaps aspiring.

Answer (score 1):

You might be thinking of [nymphomaniac](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nymphomaniac). They aren't interested in *prostitution* per se, but enjoy sex, and therefore are often prostitutes.

Answer (score -1):

The word is *meretricious* meaning "of or relating to a prostitute".  However, the word is most often used metaphorically for things things that are like prostitutes, rather than for its literal meaning.

Comment: *Meretricious* does not have any sense that means “a woman who is interested in prostitution” !  While *[meretricious](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/meretricious)* does have an obsolete sense “Of, or relating to prostitutes or prostitution”, its primary sense nowadays is one of falseness; ie “Tastelessly gaudy; superficially attractive but having no substance; falsely alluring”.

Answer (score -1):

How about "*sell-curious*" (the inverse of "*buy-curious*", naturally)?

Pre-professional.   Potential earner.   Empowered.   Ill-advised.